# Sending email to client in specific time interval

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, window, xampp

I have a user portal with 100's of members. i need to check the date of birth of every employee and need to send a birthday message automatically through email on the birth date. how can i do this. is it possible to write crone in codeigniter? if it so please suggest me some helpful links to write cron for beginners.
I am using Codeigniter and my sql database.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You should write a cron job for this one, you can follow this http://glennstovall.com/blog/2013/01/07/writing-cron-jobs-and-command-line-scripts-in-codeigniter/ . This one is also helpful http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly write a normal function in controller to send email. Make sure it satisfies following criteria

- To access the controller function no login should be there
- In controller function you should not use any session.

Then in cpanel of your server, you can set cron based on your requirement, either every minute, every hour, etc.

For your scenerio, you should set once in a day and thay will be available in common settings. Select that and enter the path to your controller function in which you have written code for sending the email.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank u somuch ... @ Niranjan N Raju

Comment: yep.. i did something like you suggested .